# Offshore Wind Data

Tags: data-request

I have a question and I would be happy to receive any leads on it from you.

I need some yearly offshore wind data sets for a given location but for several many years (say past 20 years or so). I would be happy if the data is recorded uniformly at hourly or half-hourly frequency.

Would anyone be knowing any open data source for this?

Answer (score 2):

20 years is quite the range, I only managed to find either yearly data or unclean data over 5 years.

- You will find data of 5 years [here](https://maps.nrel.gov/wind-prospector/?aL=M-cbwo%255Bv%255D%3Dt%268T4hj4%255Bv%255D%3Dt%268T4hj4%255Bd%255D%3D1&bL=groad&cE=0&lR=0&mC=60.23981116999893%2C-146.95312499999997&zL=1). Under `wind Resource > Distributed Wind Resource > Wind Speed @40m`.
- [This](https://globalwindatlas.info/) is also a nice alternative but I am not sure if you can can have multiple years data.
- This [Dataset](http://www.winddata.com/) seems to be perfect for you, but you will need to contact the maintainer for access.